# How to update imshow() window for Python OpenCV CV2

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

My current program will output an image to the user and based on user input, readjust the image as necessary.

Long story short, I am trying to find circular objects in an image file. I will be using the Hough Circle Transform. However, because many of my circles in the image are not "perfect circles", I am doing an algorithm that "guesses" the radii of the circles. However, I want to allow the user to readjust the radii as necessary.

Is there some way to ask the user for input and then based on the user input, readjust the window in imshow()? Right now, imshow() refuses to show the actual window until I use cv2.waitKey(0), at which point I can't ask for user input until the window is destroyed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can call `imshow` repeatedly without destroying it. And yes, you will likely need `waitKey`, just don't call it with 0 or it will wait indefinitely. Call it with a 1 to wait just 1 millisecond and ensure the image redraws.

Try something like:

```
while True:
    cv2.imshow('image', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    radius = input('Input radius')
    # recalculate image with new radius here...
```

Comment: I use C++ and refresh image after updated in a loop. it draws nice but when try to close window it shows me millions of previous windows to close

Comment: Are you opening the images with the same window name and from the same thread @GiorgiGvimradze ?

Comment: Solved: it was because the actual drawing (circle drawing animation) was not finished, but I was thinking it was done. Reason: loop had 360 degrees but they were radians. I actually was getting circle onto circles for a quiet long time.